# For all $n \in \mathbb{N}, |A_n|<|\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_i|$

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

For all  $n \in \mathbb{N}, |A_n|<|\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_i|$

Proof, If $A_n \subseteq \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_i$ then $A_n \lessapprox \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_i$. By transitivity we have that $|A_n| < |A_{n+1}| \leq |\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_i |$ so $|A_n|<|\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_i|$

Is this the way to go about this proof? Or am I missing something

$A_n$ is a set that satisfies if $k<n$ then $|A_k| <|A_n|$ forgot to mention this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This inequality is not strict.

Take a look at $A_i=\emptyset\quad\forall i\in\mathbb{N}$.

Then we have $0=|A_n|=|\emptyset|=|\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{\emptyset}|=|\emptyset|=0$, no $<$ here.

To show that $|A_n|\leq |\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{A_n}|$, I'd suggest you consider that $|A|\leq |B|$ if and only if you can find an injective function $f: A\to B$. Any ideas what this function could be in your case?

Comment: N+1? Some more characters

Comment: Uhm, pardon me, but I have no idea what you mean by that. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Let $|A_n|=n $ then we can map this guy to $|A_{n+1}|=n+1$. Would that be the injective map I'm looking for.

Comment: Still not entirely sure what you mean by that - in your first post you didn't specify $|A_n|$ to be even finite? No, I'd have gone about that differently: We know $A_n\subseteq \bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}{A_i}$. (Do we? If not, can you prove it?) Now, for every $x\in A_n$, we can simply map it to $x\in\bigcup{A_i}$. This map is certainly injective, because, well, it is kind of the identity, you just enlarged the codomain.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do. What are the $A_n$'s?

For example, take $A_n=\{n\cdot k\mid k\in\Bbb N\}$, then $\bigcup A_n=\Bbb N$, but for every $n\in\Bbb N$ we have that $A_n$ and $\Bbb N$ have the same cardinality.